# "No matching function for call" in constructor

Tags: c++, class, arduino

I have a `MenuItem` class declared like this

```cpp
typedef byte (menuFn)(void); //does the things
typedef String (updateFn)(void); //updates the display string

class MenuItem {
public:
  MenuItem(String dString, menuFn *onCkFn, updateFn *onUpdFn, bool clickable);
  byte click(void);
  void update(void);
  String getDisplayString(void);
  void setDisplayString(String);
private:
  String _displayString;
  bool _isClickable;
  menuFn *_onClickFn;
  updateFn *_onUpdateFn;
};
```

`MenuItem` constructor:

```
MenuItem::MenuItem(String dString, menuFn *onCkFn, updateFn *onUpdFn, bool clickable)
{
    _displayString = dString;
    _isClickable   = clickable;
    _onClickFn    = onCkFn;
    _onUpdateFn    = onUpdFn;
}
```

which is then used in another class `Menu`, like this:

```cpp
class Menu{
public:
    Menu(MenuItem menuItems[4], MenuItem staticItems[2]);
    void setItem(String itemText, byte num, menuFn itemClickFn, updateFn itemUpdateFn, bool itemClickable);
    void display(void);
    byte doItem(byte buttonPressed);
private:
    MenuItem _menuItems[4];
    MenuItem _staticItems[2];
};
```

and here is the `Menu` constructor:

```cpp
Menu::Menu(MenuItem theMenuItems[4], MenuItem theStaticItems[2])
{
  for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    _menuItems[i] = theMenuItems[i];
  }

  for (byte i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    _staticItems[i] = theStaticItems[i];
  }
}
```

When I go to compile I get this error:

```
[..]\Menu.cpp: In constructor 'Menu::Menu(MenuItem)':    
Menu.cpp:7: error: no matching function for call to 'MenuItem::MenuItem()'
Menu::Menu(MenuItem theMenuItems[4], MenuItem theStaticItems[2])
                                 ^
[..]\Menu.cpp:7:33: note: candidates are:
In file included from [..]\Menu.h:5:0,
                 from [..]\Menu.cpp:3:
[..]\MenuItem.h:11:3: note: MenuItem::MenuItem(String, byte (*)(), String (*)(), bool)
   MenuItem(String dString, menuFn *onCkFn, updateFn *onUpdFn, bool clickable);
   ^
[..]\MenuItem.h:11:3: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided
```

The error seems to point to me needing to give the parameters for the `MenuItem`s when I declare the `Menu`. I don't understand how that would work, since they're not known until I make some `menuItem` Instances and then make a `Menu` instance to contain them.

This is using the Arduino IDE BTW, so it's c++ (ish).

Comment: As the error happens in `Menu.cpp`, you should expose this part of code as well. The error is probably rather in the instancing (usage) of `class Menu` not it's declaration/definition.

Comment: Since you are not initializing your `menuItems` in the initializer list, the compiler has to default-construct them (`MenuItem::MenuItem()`) before you overwrite them in the body of your constructor (using the assignment operator)

Comment: Thanks, I included the constructor. I haven't actually used the Menu class in `main()` (or the Arduino equivalent), this error gets thrown regardless.

Comment: @Botje so to initialise them I have to provide default values in the MenuItem constructor?

Comment: Oh, I do have a MenuItem constructor, I've added it in the question now. Is that what you mean?

Comment: no, you have defined constructor with 4 parameters `MenuItem(String,... bool)` so default constructor is deleted, but before executing the body of `Menu` constructor all mambers -> `MenuItem _menuItems[4];` must be constructed by default constructor of `MenuItem`, so I say again add `MenuItem() {}` to your file. You got the answer to your question in second comment by Botje. `MenuItem()` is missing.

Comment: oh, so is that like overloading the constructor function with a version that takes no arguments? I think I get it… The `MenuItem() {}` goes in MenuItem.h, right? Thanks.

Comment: if you set default values in *MenuItem.h* for all parameters of `MenuItem` constructor `MenuItem(String dString = String(), menuFn *onCkFn = 0, updateFn *onUpdFn = 0, bool clickable = false);` should also work.